# How to search all the alphanumeric sequences in a document using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck with a problem in Regex where I need to search all the available alphanumeric sequences in a document. A document can have more than one such sequences. I am doing it in Python.

So for example if the document is like "some blah blah blah with id X12354, id 1234Z and id 12P555. All are 50 years old."

So the expected output should be:

X12354

1234Z

12P555

*Summary*: **Both alphabets and numbers must be present in a string where sequence or length doesn't matter. This string can come multiple times in a document. And it can be anywhere.**

I've tried several ways to sort out regex but it's becoming confusing every time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But both should be together without space. Like I've demonstrated in the example. X123 or 1X23 or 123X should come up. Am I getting to the point or I'm still not clear at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match between word boundaries and use a positive lookahead to assert and uppercase character and a digit:

[`\b(?=[A-Z-0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z-0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bzDcJi/1)

That would match:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right

  - `[A-Z0-9]`* Match zero or more times an uppercase character
  - `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase character
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right

  - `[A-Z0-9]*` Match zero or more times an uppercase character
  - `[0-9]` Match a digit
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match one or more times an uppercase character or a digit
- `\b` Word boundary

So, in Python, that would be:

```
import re
s = "some blah blah blah with id X12354, id 1234Z and id 12P555. All are 50 years old."
re.findall(r'\b(?=[A-Z-0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z-0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+\b', s)
```

giving:

```
['X12354', '1234Z', '12P555']
```

Comment: That's a well explanatory answer. Thanks @The fourth bird.

Comment: You are welcome. @Joe Iddon Thanks for the added example!

Comment: @Thefourthbird np

Answer (score 3):

This detects if at least an alphabet and digit exists in every small chunk of string.

```
import re
from string import punctuation
s = "some blah blah blah with id X12354, id 1234Z and id 12P555. All are 50 years old."
ans = [v for v in re.split("[ " + punctuation + "]", s) 
       if any(c.isdigit() for c in v) and any(c.isalpha() for c in v)]
['X12354,', '1234Z', '12P555']
```

`re.split("[ " + punctuation + "]", s)` splits with all punctuation and space.

Comment: That's a quite different from my approach. Since morning I wrote so many regex that my brain was in regex only mode. haha. 

But your approach looks good to me. That "." shouldn't bother much but is there a way to exclude symbols (or dots) by any chance?

Comment: @disp_name Maybe make use of `string.punctuation`

Comment: @disp_name no problem :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` to get all matches. Use two lookaheads, one for verifying that the match contains a number, another one for verifying that it contains a letter.

```
document = "some blah blah blah with id X12354, id 1234Z and id 12P555. All are 50 years old."
matches = re.findall('(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])(?=[a-z0-9]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]+', document, re.IGNORECASE)
print(matches)
```

You can try the regex online [here](https://regex101.com/r/TZnQji/1).